# Staggered GridView All items at bottom- Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-gridview

I want all the items to be at the bottom, the padding should be added at the top if the container is big. I want Grid like this https://ibb.co/zrRQ8Hz but I'm able to achieve this https://ibb.co/2820csg .

The code I've written is as follows:

```
 Container(
                                                                              margin:
                                      new EdgeInsets.all(
                                          1.0),

                                      alignment:
                                      Alignment.center,

                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                        borderRadius:
                                        BorderRadius
                                            .circular(5),
                                        border: Border.all(
                                            color: Color(0XFFc3c3c3)),
                                      ),
                                      child: Column(
                                        children: [ SizedBox(
                                          height: 5,
                                        ),
                                          RichText(
                                              text: TextSpan(children: [
                                                TextSpan(
                                                    text: "\u{20B9} ",
                                                                                                        ),
                                                TextSpan(
                                                    text: “100”,
                                                                                                    ),
                                              ])),
                                          SizedBox(
                                            height: 5,
                                          ),
                                          Container(
                                              width: double
                                                  .infinity,
                                              color: Color(0XFFc3c3c3)),
                                              child: Center(
                                                child: Text(
                                                  "Most Value",
                                                  style: TextStyle(
                                                      color: Colors
                                                          .white),
                                                ),
                                              )), SizedBox(
                                            height: 5,
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    )
```

Comment: add the code of grid view where you are creating it.

Comment: I'm not able to add the code due to the length restriction by stackoverflow.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/14livMTHgIfv4EWCUKuKPQ1rtXXzvk8z6aHNBmBfawwk/edit?usp=sharing